# PHP inside HTML issue

Tags: php, html

I have an issue with PHP files displaying information site. I'm working on a localhost and my .htaccess file is correctly configured to display .php files, as a .php file works on an html file.

But, when I tried to make a switch variable to switch between different pages dependent on a date...

```
<?php
switch(date('l')) {
   case 'Sunday': $page = 'sunday.html'; break;
   case 'Monday': $page = 'monday.html'; break;
   case 'Tuesday': $page = 'tuesday.html'; break;
   case 'Wednesday': $page = 'wednesday.html'; break;
   case 'Thursday': $page = 'thursday.html'; break;
   case 'Friday': $page = 'friday.html'; break;
   case 'Saturday': $page = 'saturday.html'; break;
}
echo file_get_contents($page);
?>
```

..then the php include code inside the .html would not work. Same with php echo, it would not display. Where might I be going wrong? My index.html (where onair.php works and is displayed on index.html) links to /programmes/schedule.html which then links to a respective page on a given day. There, the PHP code that is the same as in index.html does not display... It is simply commented in Google Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: What is `date('l')`? Try echoing just try value.

Comment: Complicate much? `include strtolower(date('l')) . '.html';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `include` the pages instead. Neither `file_get_contents` nor `echo` will execute PHP script.

```
<?php
switch(date('l')) {
   case 'Sunday': $page = 'sunday.html'; break;
   case 'Monday': $page = 'monday.html'; break;
   case 'Tuesday': $page = 'tuesday.html'; break;
   case 'Wednesday': $page = 'wednesday.html'; break;
   case 'Thursday': $page = 'thursday.html'; break;
   case 'Friday': $page = 'friday.html'; break;
   case 'Saturday': $page = 'saturday.html'; break;
}

include $page;
?>
```

Of course, you can make it simpler, too:

```
<?php
include strtolower(date('l')) . '.html';
?>
```

Comment: Is that what his question is? I could tell.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: I took an educated guess :) *".then the php include code inside the .html would not work."* and *"It is simply commented in Google Chrome."*

Answer (score 1):

PHP cannot be executed within HTML files unless you use `eval()`. You can either rename your files to .php rather than .html (better choice in my opinion), or set HTML to be run as PHP file by adding the following to your `.htaccess`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

The path might not be the same, check using a code like this:

```
readfile(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$page);
```

or include if you want to be interpreted.